# analyze postgres table via mybatis

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

I want to analyze a table before a select in mybatis. I can do that via

1. create a procedure that does the analyze
2. Before the select, run the procude via a select with statementtype=callable via mybatis

So I need a new procedure and a new line in the calling code and a new fragment in the mapper.

Is there a better way?

- Can I somehow add the analyze to the select while keeping it a plain select (not have the two in a function for example)?
- **Or can I at least trigger the analyze directly from mybatis without needing the wrapping procedure?**

**** UPDATE - How it works via a procedure: ****

```
<update id="analyzeTable" statementType="CALLABLE">
    CALL myschema.analyze_table('myschema.mytable')
</update>

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myschema.analyze_table(table_to_analyze regclass)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
    SET search_path TO ''
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_sql text := format('analyze %s', table_to_analyze);
BEGIN
    execute v_sql;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: It should be possible to execute `ANALYZE` like any other statement. Be sure to use `@Insert` or `@Update` (`<insert>` or `<update>` in XML mapper) as `ANALYZE` does not return result set. If you have any difficulty, edit the question and show us 1) what you tried and 2) how it failed.

Comment: ty for your comment @ave - using a separate update with `analyze` directly inside is not much improvement to using a generic procedure like we do (see update above). we did not get `analyze` to work directly inside the update without the procedure but it's fine. but the analyze takes up to 5 minutes from mybatis - that is our current challenge :-)

Comment: If it takes 5 mins with MyBatis, it may take 5 mins with plain JDBC. If that is not the case (i.e. MyBatis is much slower than plain JDBC), I would be happy to look into it if you could provide an executable repro. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are project templates and examples.